# TSQL issue when updating value and outputing inserted value into log table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I update a ClientFunds.Balance table column with a value and use the Ouput Inserted.Balance clause to write the value to a log table.
Occasionally the value written to the ClientFunds table is truncated whilst the value written to the log table is always correct.

First, I fill this table with the details of what will be updated on the ClientFunds table:

```
declare @ToUpdate   table
    (
        Id                      int identity(1,1),
        ClientFundId            int,
        Total                   decimal (18, 2),
        Rate                    decimal (10, 5)
    );
```

This table will hold the data to be written to the log table:

```
declare @Updated as table 
    (
        ClientFundId            int, 
        AmountBefore            decimal (18,2), 
        AmountAfter             decimal (18,2),
        ToUpdateId              int
    );
```

Here's how I update the ClientFunds table, using the @ToUpdate table and ouput the log information to the @Updated table. I've snipped a few details of the loop here but you should get the idea:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        update      cf
        set         cf.Balance = cf.Balance - (up.Total * up.Rate)
        OUTPUT      INSERTED.Id, DELETED.Balance, INSERTED.Balance, up.Id
        INTO        @Updated
        from        @ToUpdate up
        join        dbo.ClientFunds cf on cf.Id = up.ClientFundId
        where       up.Id = @CurrentId

       FETCH NEXT FROM ToUpdate_Cursor into @CurrentId;
    END
```

Now, as I said, occasionally the dbo.ClientFunds.Balance value, which is decimal (18, 2), will be written to the db with the decimal part truncated yet the inserted value output to @ToUpdate retains the correct value.

For instance, one example is 14454.36 being written to the @Updated table, and ultimately the log file, but 14454.00 being written to dbo.ClientFunds.Balance.

Any idea of what could be happening?

Thanks,
Jules

Comment: Probably you don't need cursor/loop for this, and you can achieve much better performance using `set based solution.`

Comment: What is the type of `@ToUpdate.BatchTotal`column?

Comment: Dammit, i renamed one but not the other. It should be @ToUpdate.Total which is decimal (18, 2)

Comment: Regarding cursor/loop - not sure how to do it as set based. Although the total value can be summed and ClientFunds updated just once, i need the before and after values for every single item for the log file. This would require a couple of accumulating variables while updating the log. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Try changing: `update      cf
        set         cf.Balance = cf.Balance - (up.Total * up.Rate)
        OUTPUT      INSERTED.Id, DELETED.Balance, INSERTED.Balance, up.Id
        INTO        @Updated
        From        dbo.ClientFunds cf join        @ToUpdate up 
on cf.Id = up.ClientFundId
        where       up.Id = @CurrentId`

Comment: I can see that reads better, but would it actually make any difference?

Comment: Probably not but why not try?

Comment: May as well try I suppose. Unfortunately it's not something I'll know if it's worked until after a few months...